# Swiper Js - Click para mostrar slide

Tags: slider

Necesito hacer lo siguiente, con Swiper Js,  que al hacer click en un elemento, se muestre esa diapositiva. Como hacen aquí:  http://jsfiddle.net/UDwnZ/1/   pero no lo consigo..

- Mi código:

$(document).ready(function () {
function setContentSize() {  $('.swiper-content').css({ height: $(window).height()-$('.swiper-nav').height() })  }
     /*ALL*/ var contentSwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-content", { mode:"horizontal", queueStartCallbacks: true, autoplay:true, loop: true, allowTouchMove:true, reloadImages: false, lazy: true, 
        onSlideChangeStart: function(swiper){ navSwiper.swipeTo(swiper.activeLoopIndex, 100, false)},
        onSlideChangeEnd: function (swiper) {
              if (swiper != null && swiper != undefined &&
                    navSwiper != null && navSwiper != undefined) {
                  if (swiper.activeLoopIndex != navSwiper.activeLoopIndex) {
                      navSwiper.swipeTo(swiper.activeLoopIndex, 100, false);
                  }
              }
          }
    })
     /*PORTFOLIO ARRIBA var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container .swiper-slide-top', { mode:"horizontal", lazyLoading: true, watchSlidesVisibility: 1, slideToClickedSlide: true})  */
     /*PORTFOLIO DEBAJO*/ var navSwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-nav", { slidesPerView:"auto", loop:true, createPagination: false, initialSlide: '0', 
        moveStartThreshold: 10, queueStartCallbacks: true, simulateTouch: true, initialSlide: 0,
        onSlideClick: function(swiper){ 
            var ls = swiper.loopedSlides;
              var slideIndex = swiper.clickedSlideIndex - ls;

```
          if (slideIndex >= swiper.slides.length - ls*2) {
              slideIndex = swiper.slides.length - ls*2 - slideIndex;
          }
          if (slideIndex<0) {
              slideIndex = -slideIndex;
          }                  
          navSwiper.swipeTo(slideIndex, 100, true); 
    },
    onSlideChangeStart: function(swiper){
    contentSwiper.swipeTo( swiper.activeLoopIndex, 0, false )
    },
    })    
    });
```

- Url de la web en cuestión: https://www.qode.pro/portfolio/

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var contentSwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", { pagination: '.swiper-nav', paginationClickable: true,  mode:"horizontal", initialSlide: 0, autoplay:true, loop: true, allowTouchMove:true, reloadImages: false, lazy: true  })

var navSwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-nav", { slidesPerView:"auto", simulateTouch: true, initialSlide: 0 })
$(".swiper-nav .swiper-slide").on('click', function(){ var indicedown = $(this).index(); indicedowngood = indicedown+1; contentSwiper.slideTo(indicedowngood, 500); });
});
```

Solucionado!